# Program that Returns Change PL/SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, plsql, oracle10g

I am trying to create a program that returns change in 20, 10, 5, and 1 dollar bills (all user values and inputs are integers).

For example:

```
exec Change(15, 200); 

9 Twenty Dollar Bill
1 Five Dollar Bill
```

What I have so far:

```
CREATE or REPLACE Procedure Change(
  p_MoneyDue number, p_Paid number
) as

p_Change number := p_MoneyDue - p_Paid;

BEGIN

  IF (p_Change = 0) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('You just gave me exact change! Thank you!');
  ELSIF p_MoneyDue > p_Paid THEN
    dmbs_output.put_line ('You need to give me more money!');
  ELSIF p_Change >= 100 THEN

    dbms_output.put_line ('Twenty dollar bill')
  ELSIF p_Change <= 100 THEN

    dbms_output.put_line ('10 dollar bill')
  ELSIF p_Change  THEN

    dbms_output.put_line ('5 dollar bill')

  ELSE p_Change  THEN

    dbms_output.put_line ('1 dollar bill')
  END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Skip the else's. Take steps down to 0 for each bill, starting with 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE CHANGE(
        p_moneydue NUMBER,
        p_paid     NUMBER )
AS
    p_change NUMBER := p_paid - p_moneydue;
    -- 20 10 5 1
    bill_20 NUMBER := 0;
    bill_10 NUMBER := 0;
    bill_5  NUMBER := 0;
    bill_1  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    IF (p_change = 0) THEN
        dbms_output.put_line ('You just gave me exact change! Thank you!');
    elsif p_moneydue > p_paid THEN
        dbms_output.put_line ('You need to give me more money!');
    END IF;
    IF (p_change   > 0 ) THEN
        bill_20   := TRUNC(p_change / 20);
        p_change  := p_change - (20 * bill_20);
        bill_10   := TRUNC(p_change / 10);
        p_change  := p_change - (10 * bill_10);
        bill_5    := TRUNC(p_change / 5);
        p_change  := p_change - (5 * bill_5);
        bill_1    := p_change;
        IF(bill_20 > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(bill_20 ||' Twenty Dollar Bill');
        END IF;
        IF(bill_10 > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(bill_10 ||' Ten Dollar Bill');
        END IF;
        IF(bill_5 > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(bill_5 ||' Five Dollar Bill');
        END IF;
        IF(bill_1 > 0) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(bill_1 ||' One Dollar Bill');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
BEGIN
    CHANGE( 15, 200);
END;
/
```

Comment: nice one, better then my :)

Comment: Thanks, i realized we don't need a loop

Comment: Thank you to all. I apologize for my mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

You make a lot of mistakes in your code. Have you tried to compile? The proper procedure can looks as follows

```
create or replace Procedure Change(
  p_MoneyDue number, p_Paid number
) as

   p_Change number := p_Paid - p_MoneyDue;
   p_twenty number := 0;
   p_ten number := 0;
   p_five number := 0;   
   p_one number := 0;   
BEGIN

  IF (p_Change = 0) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('You just gave me exact change! Thank you!');
  ELSIF p_MoneyDue > p_Paid THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('You need to give me more money!');
  END IF;

  WHILE p_change > 0 
  LOOP
    IF p_Change >= 20 THEN
      p_twenty := p_twenty + 1;
      p_Change := p_Change - 20;
    ELSIF p_Change >= 10 
    THEN
      p_ten := p_ten + 1;
      p_Change := p_Change - 10;
    ELSIF p_Change >= 5  THEN
      p_five := p_five + 1;
      p_Change := p_Change - 5;
    ELSE
      p_one := p_one + 1;
      p_Change := p_Change - 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  if p_twenty > 0 then 
     dbms_output.put_line (p_twenty || ' Twenty Dollar Bill');
  END IF;
  if p_ten > 0 then 
     dbms_output.put_line (p_ten || ' Ten Dollar Bill');
  END IF;
  if p_five > 0 then 
     dbms_output.put_line (p_five || ' Five Dollar Bill');
  END IF;
  if p_one > 0 then 
     dbms_output.put_line (p_one || ' One Dollar Bill');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: @Lizzie you are wellcome :) Try to compile first, sql developer (if you use it) will highlight your problematic parts. You should get use to read error messages and correct the code according to them in order to improve in you PL/SQL skills. best